# How to use MVP architecture w/ a UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, mvp

I'm using the [Model View Presenter](https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/mvp-pattern-ios/) pattern in an app.

I have a requirement to introduce a `UITabBarController` to provide tabbed navigation between routes.

I understand how I would use this in perhaps `MVC` or `MVVM` but I am unsure how to apply this without breaking away from `MVP` principles.

When I set up my tab bar, I would assume I apply the view controllers like

```
let controllers = [favoritesVC, downloadsVC, historyVC]
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
```

But now when I click a tab I would be calling the view controller direct and not instructing a scene to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without seeing more code, however I believe in MVP you should configure your view controllers using a `Configurator`.

```
class FavouritesConfigurator {

    func configureViewController(delegate: FavouritesSceneDelegate?) -> FavouritesViewController {
        let viewController = FavouritesViewController()
        let presenter = FavouritesPresenter(view: viewController)
        presenter.delegate = delegate
        viewController.setPresenter(presenter)
        return viewController
    }
}
```

Your coordinator start method should simply be invoking the `FavouritesConfigurator` and returning a `ViewController` configured with your presenter etc.

You can use the return value of that `FavouritesConfigurator` to setup your views.

It is simply a case of moving each views configuration away from a start method and calling that configurator directly. This doesn't violate any principles as your components are still isolated, testable and invoked correctly.

Again, without seeing your code it's difficult to be exact, but try this:

```
let controllers = [FavouritesConfigurator().configureViewController(delegate: self),...,...]
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
```